# Please anyone tell me how to generate presigned Url S3 for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3

**I am getting the Aws storage Url using this method.**

```dart
getDownloadUrl() async {
  final user = await AmplifyAuthCognito().getCurrentUser();

  try {
    final result = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: user.userId);

    ('Got URL: ${result.url}');
  } on StorageException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Error getting download URL: $e');
  }
}
```

****Please tell me Now After this how do create the presigned Url? ****

Comment: Try to use Amplify.Storage.getPresignedUrl method

Comment: There are no methods of Amplify.Storage.getPresignedUrl .